# Why is my string converting into a Fixnum when using .to_i rather than an integer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm running this line:

`<%= @date[i].created_at.strftime('%d').to_i.class %>`

and the output is a fixnum rather than an int. Why is this?

From the controller:

`@date = Lesson.find(:all, :order => 'created_at ASC')`

Comment: What's an `int`? At least Ruby doesn't have it.

Comment: An integer. Sorry for the shorthand

Comment: Let me Google that for you: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Fixnum.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no such thing `int` in Ruby. `Fixnum` is the class of small numbers like `1` or `2` that fit into a machine word, and it's a subclass of `Integer`. Check the following:

```
irb(main):004:0> 42.class
=> Fixnum
irb(main):005:0> 42.is_a? Fixnum
=> true
irb(main):006:0> 42.is_a? Integer
=> true
irb(main):007:0> 42.is_a? Numeric
=> true
irb(main):008:0> 42.is_a? Object
=> true
```

So your value is a `Fixnum`, an `Integer`, a `Numeric` and an `Object` at the same time ;) This effect is called [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) and it might surprise you in this context because in some other programming languages numbers are treated in a special way (they have some kind of "native" type). In Ruby, numbers are just objects.

Comment: Why am I unable to perform certain operations due to it being a Fixnum, that's what I don't understand

Comment: @Zack: Which operations? It's an `Integer`, it has all the methods.

Comment: Never mind. I figured it out. Thanks for all of your help Niklas. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

> A Fixnum holds Integer values that can be represented in a native machine word (minus 1 bit). If any operation on a Fixnum exceeds this range, the value is automatically converted to a Bignum.

`Fixnum` is, in fact, a child class of `Integer`.

See http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Integer.html